# PHP - Missing tags when exporting database as XML with XMLWriter

Tags: php, mysql, xml, xmlwriter

I am working with XMLWriter to try and export a database that currently contains about 6700 rows.

From what I have seen, doing this should be relatively straightforward, but during the process of printing the XML, it will not close off an element, therefore creating an error.

```
$xml = new XMLWriter();

$xml->openURI("php://output");
$xml->startDocument('1.0', 'UTF-8');
$xml->setIndent(true);

$xml->startElement('doc');

while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($getResult)) {
  $xml->startElement("item");

  $xml->startElement("id");
    $xml->writeRaw($row['id']);
  $xml->endElement();

  $xml->startElement("type");
    $xml->writeRaw($row['type']);
  $xml->endElement();

  $xml->startElement("name");
    $xml->writeRaw($row['name']);
  $xml->endElement();

  $xml->endElement();
}

$xml->endElement();

$xml->flush();
```

At some point during the process, I will see something like this in the XML output:

```
<type>exampleTypetype>
```

It will then continue on printing the XML.

I am still relatively new to PHP, so I would appreciate any insight into what could be going on here.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You're using [`XMLWriter::writeRaw()`](http://php.net/xmlwriter-write-raw) and as you do that, you need to take care of the correct XML encoding on your own as this writes the bytes as-is.

And as your error description shows, you do not happen to properly encode those raw bytes into valid XML first.

As it further shows, you're not aware of that. Most likely because you expect the XMLWriter extension to already encode the data for you.

Then you're perhaps looking for [`XMLWriter::text()`](http://php.net/xmlwriter-text) or in case you need to encode binary data into the XML, for [`base64_encode()`](http://php.net/base64_encode).